# Capturar números em Arquivo e salvar resposta (Linux)

Tags: linux

Eu tenho um arquivo com os seguintes dados:

```
XXZ 000000000000012 MARCIO
XXZ 000000000000022 NILSON
XXZ 000000000000032 WALTER
XXZZZ 000000000000042 CARLOS
XXXZZZ 000000000000000 MARIA
```

Eu gostaria de pular os primeiros caracteres e capturar depois do espaço os números e salvar em um arquivo com a resposta.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
sed -r 's/.* ([0-9]{14}).*/\1/' exemplo > saida
```

onde:

- `.*` apanha uma seguenência de caracteres terminada por espaço
- `([0-9]{14})` apanha e guarda (em \1) uma sequência de 14 digitos
- `.*`  apanha o resto da linha
- `s/.../\1/`  e substitui os anteriores pelos digitos quardados

Já agora usando grep podemos procurar e extrair sequências de 14 digitos

```
grep -Po '\d{14}' exemplo > saida
```

Comment: Obrigado @JJoao! Funcionou!